# Sentient AI (called "Mother") flees Earth with survivors

Tags: story-identification, books

Following Earth's explosion, a sentient AI named "mother", equipped with a super weapon flees the invading forces with the last three (adolescents) humans aboard.

It's a 3-volume series, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Were these YA books? Your description *sort of* sounds like K. A. Applegate's *Remnants* series but the details don't quite match.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191179/sf-novel-featuring-children-on-a-spaceship

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could possibly be 'Anvil of Stars' by Greg Bear.

1. it is a two-part story (Forge of God is the first book)
2. spaceship contains only children/teenagers
3. there are robots aboard the ship which the children refer to as 'moms'
4. Earth is destroyed (in the first book)
5. the ship contain some sort of super-weapon